# How to create accurate CollisionShapes for my 3D .USDZ model?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

This is how my model looks like and it's collision shapes (pink color).

[image]

My problem with this is that when I try to tap on the bottommost part of my model (the circle), I can't do that, because the uppermost part of the model's CollisionShape is in the way.

This is how i tried to create an accurate collisionShape for my model:

```
@objc private func placeObject() {
 
let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "Laryngeal")
let geom = entity.findEntity(named: "Geom")
 
for children in geom!.children {
  let childModelEntity = children as! ModelEntity
  childModelEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: childModelEntity.model!.mesh)])
}
 
let modelEntity = ModelEntity()
modelEntity.addChild(entity)
 
let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity)

arView.installGestures([.all],for: modelEntity)

arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
```

}

So my question is, how can i create the most accurate collisionShape which perfectly fits my model?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing. Import your .usdz model in reality-composer apply physics and collision as needed. And select collision shape to automatic.

After that export your model in a .reality file (using cmd+E) and observe a collision shape there ( it might be useful)